# c# threading access to other thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have this error: Cross-thread operation not valid: "Control 'progressBar1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on." I can't seem to figure out how to fix it.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.panel1.Visible = false;
        this.panel2.Visible = true;
        new Thread(ProgressBAR).Start();
    }
    private void ProgressBAR()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5);
        for (int start = 0; start <= 100; start++)
        {
            this.progressBar1.Value = start;
            Thread.Sleep(5);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the progress bar's `Invoke` method to execute the assignment on the control's primary thread:

```
this.progressBar1.Invoke((Action) () => this.progressBar1.Value = start, null);
```

You only have to do this when `progressBar1.InvokeRequired` is true.  Consider using [this extension class](https://github.com/cadenza/cadenza/blob/master/src/Cadenza.Core/Cadenza.ComponentModel/SynchronizeInvokeCoda.cs) (shameless self-promotion, sorry about that).  Then you can forget whether or not you are on the right thread:

```
this.progressBar1.AutoInvoke(() => this.ProgressBar1.Value = start);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.panel1.Visible = false;
    this.panel2.Visible = true;
    new Thread(ProgressBAR).Start();
}

private void ProgressBAR()
{
    Thread.Sleep(5);
    for (int start = 0; start <= 100; start++)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => this.progressBar1.Value = start));
        Thread.Sleep(5);
    }
}
```

Because of limitations in the OS, you cannot access a UI element from any thread other than the thread that it was created on.  The call to [`Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) will synchronously invoke the call to update the `ProgressBar`'s value on the main thread.

Answer (score -1):

You must execute the specified delegate on the thread that owns the control's underlying window handle.

For more information see
[Control.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx)

Try this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.panel1.Visible = false;
   this.panel2.Visible = true;
   new Thread(ProgressBAR).Start();
}

private void ProgressBAR()
{
   Thread.Sleep(5);
   for (int start = 0; start <= 100; start++)
   {
      this.Invoke(new Action(() => this.progressBar1.Value = start));
      Thread.Sleep(5);
   }
}
```

Comment: Calling `BeginInvoke` without a corresponding `EndInvoke` is a bug and **will leak memory**.

Comment: @cdhowie:edited Invoke()

Comment: @user2267264:use Invoke instead BeginInvoke.

Comment: So basically use my answer.  :)

Comment: @Dan:I didn't use your answer,be sure:)